# Huawei P30 Lite: Video Freezing couple seconds in while audio still playing

Tags: android, video, freeze, huawei-mobile-services

Video starts playing for a couple seconds before it freezes on a frame while audio still continues to play in the background. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: hi@SamJones, Can you provide more details on this issue?